# How an event stream JavaScript reader can trigger page refresh?

Tags: javascript, php, loops, variables, event-stream

It is the first time in years I'm posting a question to any community. I've been working with PHP/SQL for years so far and during this time i never had to deal with JavaScript.

So maybe you can provide me with some help cause i tried everything already without solving this problem.

The script below is currently working properly in a PHP powered website. In the event stream I'm posting updates read by dyntasks.php from a text file on the filesystem updated by the app engine

```
?><script type="text/javascript">
if(typeof(EventSource)!=="undefined") {
    var eSource = new EventSource("dyntasks.php");
    eSource.onmessage = function(event, previous) { 
        //if ( (previous !== event.data) ) {location.reload(true);};
        document.getElementById("serverData").innerHTML = event.data; 
    };
} else { document.getElementById("serverData").innerHTML="Whoops! Your browser doesn't receive server-sent events."; }
</script><?php
```

The script updates a block on the page and it is working properly.

The block is showing text in this form:

```
2017-03-21 16:08:15: task 21624 completed
2017-03-21 16:11:08: task 21627 completed
2017-03-21 16:36:01: task 21629 completed
2017-03-21 17:52:08: task 21635 completed
updating...
```

Now I need to UPDATE THE WHOLE PAGE when a specific task id is completed. The "taskid" is already stored in a variable and it is also available in the querystring.

> /index.php?id=taskmanager&fullpage=21624

I tried for like 20 hours to update the JavaScript code but i couldn't make it to arrange it in such a way that it can trigger the

> location.reload(true)

Can you please provide me with some hint? I think i only need to know how to save the event.data variable into a global variable to be used before the function to trigger the update but any further advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Use window.location.reload();

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do it is by change the event stream from strings to *message objects*.

Instead of sending:

```
echo "2017-03-21 16:08:15: task 21624 completed";
```

You can do:

```
echo json_encode(array(
    "action" => "task completed",
    "task id" => 21624,
    "ts" => "2017-03-21 16:08:15"
));
```

Then in JavaScript you can do:

```
eSource.onmessage = function(event) { 
    event = JSON.parse(event);
    if (event.action === "task complete") {
        document.location.href = "/index.php?id=taskmanager&fullpage=" + event["task id"];
    }
};
```

Comment: the code portion you mentioned should be replaced in the dyntasks.php then, right? i was thinking that maybe i should change the approach and send the event straight at the end of the task execution rather than writing a string in a log file on the disk...